# SharePoint Calendar Daily Entry limit

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, custom-list, calendar

We use a group SharePoint calendar for leave.

Is there any way to limit the number of entries on any one given day

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately,** you can't control the total number of entries that should be added per day as OOTB.

---

**The workaround:**

**In my opinion,** the flexible workaround is creating an **Event Receiver** on `itemAdding` to check the total number of the entries that created today **before** adding any new entry to prevent adding any new entries **If** the number of created entries is greater than the specified Entry Limit.

**To get starting,** check the below links:

- [How to: Create an Event Receiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx)
- [How to: Create an Event Receiver for a Specific List Instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398052.aspx)
- [Steps To Create Item Event Receivers In SharePoint](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-create-item-event-receivers-in-sharepoint-2013-using-c-sharp-server-object-m/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use PreSaveAction(custom the function in calendar event new form) for calendar event validation, and call ListData.svc to check how many events are created, for example:

/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Calendar2?$filter=StartTime ge datetime'2017-12-22T00:00:00Z'